# Can you install an LED floodlight in a regular ceiling fan?

Tags: lighting, led

I'm considering buying this [9 Watt BR30 reflector LED bulb](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K1AHQXS) to replace a 60W incandescent bulb on a ceiling fan:

[image]

The ceiling fan actually has 4 lights (I only need one of the lights so the other 3 have burned out bulbs).

Will it work? Also, the "light fixture socket" has a "cover" around it, do LED bulbs heat a lot?

Answer (score 7):

All lamps have a size designation which is stated in eights of an inch (1/8").

That particular lamp will most likely not fit in your fixture if it is designed to take a standard A-lamp. That is an R30 size lamp which is 3-3/4" wide. An R20 style lamp (2-1/2" wide) would be more in line size wise with an A-lamp, which is actually an A-19.

[image]

Comment: There are many R20 LED bulbs available in different color spectrums. I like 1000bulbs.com for online light bulb shopping. They have options that should work for you: https://www.1000bulbs.com/category/led-r20-flood-lights/

Answer (score 0):

there are so many brands and types of LED lamps.  Some get hot some do not.  All lamps give off heat though...compared to a 60W or more traditional light bulb...there's most likely less heat in an LED.  But to answer your question....sure you can use an LED flood there.  there are many options.  I like 1000bulbs.com for buying stuff for the house.  pretty inexpensive and good quality items.  I've replaced about 75% of my light bulbs at home with LED and really noticed alot on my electric bills.

Answer (score 0):

We have the newer ceiling fans which take the tiny bulbs w/tiny screws, so we bought four adapters to take traditional light bulbs. However, they have a power limiter on the fan light unit where if you put more than 160 total watts in there, the whole thing won't work.

So, we bought LED bulbs that look like the traditional bulbs & have the same screw end, but they stick out about 4 inches from the outside of the glass covers & look really dorky. But, we are happy with the much increased light output & fewer watts being used.

Comment: If you mean candelabra bases when you say *tiny screws*, there are now small LED bulbs with those bases so you can avoid the adapters.

Answer (score 0):

Probably.  The only things that would cause you to not use an LED bulb would be that the housing is too small, the cover is too small (however you don't have to use this), or if you had a dimmer that was not compatible with the LED bulb.  Given that we don't have the exact dimensions of your housing and cover, my advise would be buy a bulb and try it out.

LED permeate much less heat than incandescent bulbs and use less energy.  Also they are not prone to failing with vibration (although I know some will argue this) as other bulb types so as of right now they would be the ultimate bulb type for a fan.

Also not that there are LEDs in all sizes now.  I just purchased 6 LED dimmable bulbs that output close to what a 100W incandescent would and they are the exact same size.  These ran me about $16 a piece.